# cannot install crytpo in a my nodejs app using npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Hello guys I have a nodeJS App, and I need to install crytpo for some passwords confidentiality .

**I'm using express 3.0.0**
**node 5.5.0

npm : 3.3.12**

When I tap `npm install crypto` the cmd tell the following :

[image]

**This my file package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "Training2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
    "ejs": "*",
    "express": "3.0.0"
  }
}
```

Could you help me ot please! Thanks

Comment: Please directly copy the error here

Comment: The install was successful. That warning is not related to your install. npm will give warnings unrelated to your current operation. It's one of the most confusing aspects of it.

Comment: As an aside, do you actually want to install the `crypto` module from npm? Node.js has a built-in `crypto` module. Did you actually want to use that instead?

Comment: Freyday, absolutely the module crypto have been installed but , when I do something like : var crypto = require('crypto'); the compilateur of webstorm don't know what is crypot it says : Node.js core module sources are not configured